# Combine 2 sections of aws ec2 describe-instance output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

I am trying to combine the following 2 commands into 1

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[].Instances[].State[].{InstanceState:Name} --output table

aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[].{InstanceName:Value} --output table
```

My last ditch plan is to call both separately but I am sure there is a way to do this in 1 line. The closet I got was 1 table with the incorrect instance name using the command below.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[].Instances[].State[].{InstanceState:Name,InstanceName:Tags.Value} --output table

Sample output

    Describe Instances
InstanceName | InstanceState
Name A       | running
Name B       | stopped
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Are you trying to get the name and state of all instances?

Comment: Yes the name and the state of all instances
Correction: the tag name and state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be more than one tag but only one value for other attributes like instance state, so get the first element in the tags assuming it always has the name for all instances. I tried the following and it worked fine for me:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[].Instances[].[State.Name,Tags[0].Value] --output table
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it is exactly what I needed but I would like to know more on adding more tags. Specifically how to structure the command and have it structured in the same format if I need more than 2 tags?

Comment: As long as you tag the instances uniformly like Tag[0] is Name, Tag[1] is some_info, you can query them by indexing correctly. For example, to query the first and second element in the Tag,


`aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[].Instances[].[State.Name,Tags[0].Value,Tags[1].Value] --output table`

Answer (score 0):

You can grab a specific tag like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{State:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0]}' --output table
```